# OpenCL Compiler Error (dynamic allocation)

Tags: c, opencl

I have a problem compiling an OpenCL kernel, and can't explain why it happens that way.

I get the following error:

```
Cannot select: 0x7ff1a9871610: i64,ch = dynamic_stackalloc 0x7ff1ab114cb0, 0x7ff1a9870f10, 0x7ff1a9870710 [ORD=12] [ID=21]
  0x7ff1a9870f10: i64 = bitcast 0x7ff1a9871710 [ID=19]
    0x7ff1a9871710: v2i32 = IGILISD::MOVSWZ 0x7ff1a9870d10, 0x7ff1a986eb10, 0x7ff1a986eb10, 0x7ff1a986eb10 [ID=15]
      0x7ff1a9870d10: i32 = Constant<8> [ID=12]
      0x7ff1a986eb10: i32 = Constant<0> [ID=9]
      0x7ff1a986eb10: i32 = Constant<0> [ID=9]
      0x7ff1a986eb10: i32 = Constant<0> [ID=9]
  0x7ff1a9870710: i64 = bitcast 0x7ff1a9871110 [ID=18]
    0x7ff1a9871110: v2i32 = IGILISD::MOVSWZ 0x7ff1a986eb10, 0x7ff1a986eb10, 0x7ff1a986eb10, 0x7ff1a986eb10 [ID=14]
      0x7ff1a986eb10: i32 = Constant<0> [ID=9]
      0x7ff1a986eb10: i32 = Constant<0> [ID=9]
      0x7ff1a986eb10: i32 = Constant<0> [ID=9]
      0x7ff1a986eb10: i32 = Constant<0> [ID=9]
In function: mmul
ERROR: Build Program (-11)
```

which I know is caused by one of the following two lines (If I remove both of them, the kernel compiles file)

```
uchar valc = valuec[j] ^ ((block_b[(k+i) + block_size * ty] >> (8*j)) & 0xff) ;
```

and

```
 value = value | ((int) valuec[j] << (8*j)) ;
```

where valuec is defined:

```
  __private uchar valuec[bytes];
```

and block_b is an argument to the kernel

```
..,__local int* restrict block_b)
```

Any ideas? It has to do with the combination of the array valuec[j] and the shift operator.
I can compile the kernel with the line

```
valuec[j] = 0
```

or with the lines

```
   uchar hello = 0;
   uchar valc = hello ^ ((block_b[(k+i) + block_size * ty] >> (8*j)) & 0xff) ;
```

but NOT with the lines

```
   uchar hello = valuec[j];
   uchar valc = hello ^ ((block_b[(k+i) + block_size * ty] >> (8*j)) & 0xff) ;
```

or with the lines  (where valuec[j] is definitely equal to 0)

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i < bytes ; i++) [
        valuec[i]=0;
     }
    uchar hello = valuec[j];
    uchar valc = hello ^ ((block_b[(k+i) + block_size * ty] >> (8*j)) & 0xff) ;
```

Comment: Which OpenCL platform is this? That looks like an internal compiler failure, not a syntax error, so this may be a bug in the implementation rather than a problem with your code. Have you tried the code on other OpenCL platforms?

Comment: OpenCl 1.2. I'll try on 1.1

Comment: Actually, I meant which device are you targeting (e.g. NVIDIA, AMD, Intel etc, on Windows/OS X/Linux). Different versions of OpenCL within the same platform probably won't make a difference.

Comment: Currently running on 
Name: Iris Version: OpenCL C 1.2

I don't know yet which GPU i'll be using for deployment

Comment: IMHO without seeing the whole kernel and if you haven't build it with `-cl-opt-disable` we cannot be sure that those lines are actually causing the problem. `-cl-opt-disable` removes optimization. I had a case where compiler was basically optimizing the whole kernel out, when I removed one line from the end and I thought for a long that the line was causing the error, even it was completely other.

Comment: Just built it with -cl-opt-disable